# Lambda Expression didn't work in post with specific label

Tags: html, css, xml, lambda, blogger

so I have searching about lambda expression but somehow it didn't work on my blog so I need some advice why this's not work, plus is it okay if I put this not in `<data:post.body/>` section. but in bottom of `</b:skin>`

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels all (label => label.name in {"Project"})'>
<style type='text/css'>
/*<![CDATA[*/
.rl-item{
    float:left;
    width: 190px !important;
    height: 114px !important;
    margin: 5px 3px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.rl-item img{width: 190px !important;height: 110px !important;}

#main.main.section {
    padding-right: 0;
    border-right: none !important;
}
/*]]>*/
</style>                
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will only work if it is added between the statement -

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
<!-- Your Code -->
</b:loop>
```

This `b:loop` statement is found inside the `Blog` widget.

If the code is included outside the `b:loop` statement, then the `b:if` statement won't work because it won't be able to find the namespace of `data:post` (The only globally available namespace in Blogger template is `data:blog`)